# Introductory statistics overview

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference

Here is my way of viewing inferential statistics so far:

1. Sampling distribution - basic concept
   What's the point of inferential statistics here? Oh, well, estimating parameters! OK so here comes:
2. Estimation:
   a. point estimation;
   b. interval estimation = confidence interval.
   Pretty well. But now comes:
3. Hypothesis testing. **Is there any link between confidence intervals and hypothesis testing or are they separate concepts? Is 'estimation' the link? How come? I can't see the link between estimation and hypothesis testing...**

Comment: It is unclear what do you mean and what is your question. Between the lines I read that you are basically asking us to summarize for you the whole mathematical statistics handbook in few sentences. In either of the cases your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Sorry. My questions are those from number 3.

Comment: Have you tried searching through the page: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16312/what-is-the-difference-between-confidence-intervals-and-hypothesis-testing ..?

Comment: 1,2,3 were just my study flow. I understood that the basis is 'sampling distribution'. Then I was wondering what's the point of inferential statistics? Inference of population parameters (estimation). Now, I want to know if there is a connection between confidence intervals and hypothesis testing.